# Need If statement to check range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a subroutine that calls another subroutine for specific locations and creates pivot tables. I just realized that if there is no data for a particular location in my raw data, the macro crashes. I'd like to setup some If then statements so that it won't try and run a particular Call statement unless that location exists. Here's the subroutine:

```
Sub EachLocationPivot()

    Call LocationPivot("Barker Library")
    Call LocationPivot("Dewey Library")
    Call LocationPivot("Hayden Library")
    Call LocationPivot("Music Library")
    Call LocationPivot("Rotch Library")

    End Sub
```

The location name information can be found in the range EF4:EF500 on a sheet called "Raw Data". So if the location "Music Library" does not exist in that range, I don't want the line Call LocationPivot("Music Library") to run. It should then go onto the next Call line and perform the same test but for that location name.

Comment: Maybe you should add that check into the `LocationPivot` subroutine?

Comment: `If IsError(Application.Match(str, Sheets("Raw Data").Range("EF4:EF500"), False)) Then Exit Sub`  -- where `str` is whatever variable name you have as a required argument in the `LocationPivot` subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close to what you need.  `c` probabaly should be a variant...

```
With Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("EF4:EF500")
    Set c = .Find("Barker Library")
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Call LocationPivot("Barker Library")
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Great!  Could you please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the green downwards facing arrow and then the Up arrow if you found it helpful?  Thanks,

Comment: Could you please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the green downwards facing arrow and then the Up arrow if you found it helpful? Thanks, – Jim